# Talend: how to read the 2 first lines of a .txt/.csv file, and get the date from the line beginning with "Generated:"

Tags: csv, file, text, header, talend

I read data from a .csv file the usual way with a tFileInputDelimited component, which I read and output to my local PostgreSQL database.

But my problem is that I need to get the date from the 2 first lines of the file.
The 2 first lines are not column separated... but just a 2 line header.

I would need to know what component to use and how to set them to:

- read the 2 first lines
- get the line which starts with "Generated:"
- get the date which is just after ":"

Example header, the 2 first lines:

```
Report Title:this_is_the_title
Generated: Nov-27-2020, 14:03:01 CET
```

Is it possible to do that with Talend, and which components would be best?
I do not know all the components yet, and try to use  tFileInputDelimited, but it does not seems to work with it.

==== EDIT ====
I am trying to do it with tFileInputRegex, this could work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Use this schema for the input file :

[image]

In the `tFileInputDelimited`, specify "@" as the field separator (set the entire line as 1 record) and set the limit at 2 to read only the first 2 lines:

[image]

In the `tFilterRow`, Click the Advanced Mode, add this code to keep only the "Generated" line :

[image]

In the `tJavaRow`, add this code to extract the date :

```
output_row.line = input_row.line.substring("Generated:".length() + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now managed to use a tFileInputRegex with "^Generated:(.*)$", which seems to do the same as your proposition. So i use a tFileInputDelimiter for the data in colums, and a tFileInputRegex for the date in the 2 line header. Does it sounds ok for you ?

Comment: @Malo  In my opinion,  tFileInputDelimiter (with the limit setting) and the tFilterRow are simpler and meet the requirement of  your use-case.